# Error Inserting Vlookup Formula in Excel using Cells.Range

Tags: vba, excel, range, vlookup

Anyone can help me on the following code below? I am trying to insert a Vlookup Formula in the worksheet. However, i am getting error

> Application Defined or Object Defined Error

```
Sub WriteFormulasInSheet()

Dim lRow As Long


    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Consolidator").Activate
    Cells.Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(lRow, 4)).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],MAP!$N:$P,2,0),"""")"


End Sub
```

Anything that i miss in the code? Your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried it outside of vba with one cell...start there

Comment: yes, i already tried....if simple formula like If only or sumifs, it is working...but  for vlookup....it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

You should use Formula, not Value.

```
Cells.Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(lRow, 4)).FormulaR1C1
```